# Array of JSONs from url, The Array elements are changing and put them in a tableView in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I have an Array of JSONs from url, The Array elements are changing, sometimes 3 sometimes 4 or more

I need to do this in swift 3

the array looks like this

```
[
{
ERTFN: "11111",
Name: "AAAAA",
Rlab: "BBBBB",
Rstatus: "CCCCC"
},
{
ERTFN: "22222",
Name: "ZZZZZ",
Rlab: "XXXXX",
Rstatus: "YYYYYY"
},
{
ERTFN: "33333",
Name: "DDDDD",
Rlab: "FFFFF",
Rstatus: "GGGGGG"
}
]
```

I don't need the keys to be in the tableView 
please help me with the code

Comment: can you give more input exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Abdullah Alkurdi error please? where are you stuck ? What have you done? Any code you can share?

Comment: As i am seeing you have an array of dictionaries here. To achieve your job, fetch your dictionary from the array. Convert this dictionary to `mutable dictionary`. Change your object and put it back to the same index of array. Reload the table.

Comment: Hi Harvant, thanks for your help, this sounds like what I need to do, please code you explain the code of fetching the dectionary and converting to mutable dicitionary

Comment: @Bhupat Bheda, for this example, I need to create a tableView of three cells as we heve 3 elements in the array, and these three cells each contain 1111 , AAAA, BBB, CCCC for the first cell and so on

Answer (score 1):

you can use `JSONSerialization.jsonObject` method and get an array output from the jsonData then iterate over the array and get data.

```
  do{
    let allData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: yourData, options: mutableContainers) as! NSArray
   for item in allData! {
     var ertfn = item["ERTFN"]
       }
   }catch{
     print(error)
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let displayData = [["name":"1111","done":"BBB","Notdone":"CCC"]]
```

this code will come in cellForRowAt

```
    let dictionary = displayData[indexPath.row] 
    var Allkey = ""
   for (key, value) in dictionary {
       if Allkey == ""
       {
            Allkey += String("\(value)")
       }
       else
       {
           Allkey += String(",\(value)")
       }
  }
  print(Allkey)
```

output of above code is "1111,BBB,CCC"